# Yii CGridView showing more than 10 records per page

Tags: yii, records, cgridview

So here I've got a table which has more than 10 records.

In each admin.php page, the CGridView only shows a limited 10 records then to the next page. How or where should I add in order for it to display more than 10 records per page?

Please advise. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is just modifying `$model->search()` in this way:

```
 ...
 return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => 20,
        ),
```